# How to call selector method from RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers(GitHub)

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, xcode7, call

I am using https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers to swipe between my controllers.
Every things runs fine, how ever i want to add a UIButton, on which i can go to another view controller (with out swiping.)
i have imported a class from RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers in which they are using below code to create a uibutton

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT)];

        [navigationView addSubview:button];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [button setTitle:[buttonText objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the selector method is below:

```
-(void)tapSegmentButtonAction:(UIButton *)button {

    if (!self.isPageScrollingFlag) {

        NSInteger tempIndex = self.currentPageIndex;

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        //%%% check to see if you're going left -> right or right -> left
        if (button.tag > tempIndex) {

            //%%% scroll through all the objects between the two points
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex+1; i<=button.tag; i++) {
                [pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL complete){

                    //%%% if the action finishes scrolling (i.e. the user doesn't stop it in the middle),
                    //then it updates the page that it's currently on
                    if (complete) {
                        [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:i];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }

        //%%% this is the same thing but for going right -> left
        else if (button.tag < tempIndex) {
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex-1; i >= button.tag; i--) {
                [pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:^(BOOL complete){
                    if (complete) {
                        [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:i];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i call this method from my view controller it doesn't respond the same way as it does in RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers.

Now below is the code i am using to call this selector method.

```
[rkSwipeControllrObject tapSegmentButtonAction:myButtonObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have made "tapSegmentButtonAction" method public by declaring this in the RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers.h file.